Interpretation of the aspect “何年も生きている” in this context

あなたが何年も変わらぬ姿のまま生きていることを彼らは知っているんですか？

This “生きている” in particular here interested me. I know that “〜ている” can very often mean “have been ..." implying a constant state since the past, as in say “６時から起きている。” but is this interpretation also triggered with “何年も” for this specific verb which is seldom found as “生きる” to begin with? as in does this mean “Do they know you have been living for many years without your appearance changing?” or does it simply mean “Do they know you( will) live for many years without your appearance changing.”? and if it mean the former, how does one express the latter?

I interpreted it as the former. As for the latter, I think the sentence would be あなたが何年も変わらぬ姿のまま生きていくことを彼らは知っているんですか
